# How to run tests in PhoneGap

Tags: testing, cordova

How do I run tests located in in the /www/spec folder?

Sorry for this question, but PhoneGap is totally lacking documentation.

Comment: Do you really think PhoneGap doesn't have good documentation? - http://docs.phonegap.com

Comment: Documentation is good, but not enough. Getting Started guides only tell you how to set up the environment, no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `www/spec.html` file in a browser.

Comment: Really? It is the first thing I have tried but... 1. I get no output running that page in a browser (even if there are some tests) 2. How can I test code in a browser if that code depends on the device?

Comment: I try to guess the answers. 1. All tests are passing 2. No way to run tests in the simulator. I can only simulate events in a browser (mocks, triggering, etc.). Can you point me out any valuable resources about PhoneGap/PhoneGap testing? (if any) Thanks!

Comment: I will say that after enjoying the first couple of days with the original PhoneGap behavior I ripped the guts out of that fileset and replaced it with my own code.  Much later I decided to delete the bloat and stumbled over this spec.html and the Jasmine tests and such.  I suppose one could read the docs on Jasmine to find out more.  http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html